# Remove the emoticon key from android kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, emoticons

Is there any way to programatically hide the emoticon key in kitkat keyboard? I have marked the key in the image given below.

[image]

I need to remove this icon from the keyboard displayed when I tap an edit text in my application. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

1)
Do a long press on the button you marked in your picture. There should pop up a small window.
Hit **Input languages** and deselect Emoji / Emoticons / ....

2)
If the first way does not work, download the android kitkat keyboard and use this instead of your current keyboard.

Comment: Can I remove that programatically for my application only??

Comment: I fear not. You could try to solve it with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=de)? Caution! Root is necessary!